# Trying to explicitly type the results from the LINQ Select method

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I’m still trying to wrap my head around some of the nuances of LINQ to Entities methods. With the code block below, I’d normally use the type `var` for the object (Comment 1 below), but because the `foreach` loop is not nested in the `switch/case` block (Comment 2 below), I need to define the type of `emailList` outside of the `switch/case` block, and I need to define it explicitly (`var` is no longer an option). So what is the proper type for `emailList`? The compiler doesn’t like `IQueryable<vwMaterialsDueAutoEmail>`. Besides, when the Emailstate is CancelNotice (Comment 3 below), the type of `IQueryable<vwMaterialsDueAutoEmail>` won’t work. The compiler seems to like `IQueryable` (Comment 4 below) with no generic type `<T>`, but when I use try to use `emailList` in foreach, I have not results, and all attempts at retrieving an `email` property (`email.CaseName`, `email.EmailAddress`...) fail miserably (Comment 5 below). I’m 80% confident that the fix is correctly typing `emailList` and perhaps using some flavor of cast when I assign values to it, but I’m not sure how to pull it off.

```
   IQueryable emailList; // Comment 4: IQueryable with no <Type>
   string subject;
   string body = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(parameters.EmailBodyPath() + 
      @"\" + parameters.EmailBodyFile());
   switch (parameters.EmailState)
   {
      case EmailState.MaterialsDue:
         emailList = context.vwMaterialsDueAutoEmail.Select(d => new 
         // Comment 1: Normally I'd use var emailList.
         {
            CaseID = d.CaseID,
            CaseName = d.CaseName,
            EmailAddress = d.EmailAddress
         });
         break;
      case EmailState.CancelNotice: //Comment 3: The other possible case.
         emailList = context.vwRTCancelNoticeEmails.Select(d => new 
         // Omitted. Code similar to MaterialsDue.
      default:
         emailList = context.vwMaterialsDueAutoEmail; 
         // Will never be executed. Existence prevents "Use of unassigned variable" erorr 
         break; 
   }
   foreach (var email in emailList) 
   // Comment 2: foreach is not in the switch/case block above
   {
      subject = "Materials Due: " + email.CaseName;
      body = body.Replace("_CaseName_", email.CaseName);
      //Comment 5: email problematic
      SendEmail(email.EmailAddress, subject, "This is the body.");
   }
```

Comment: Don't use anonymous types.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `new { Property = value... }` you are using anonymous types. And an anonymous type has, obviously, no name. And since the type has no name, you cannot define it explicitly. (Officially it has a name, but that one is assigned by the compiler...)

Further more, since you use anonymous types at different location, there is a big change all those types will be different, so it is hard to assign them to the same `emailList` since `emailList` would need to be three types at once.

A solution could be to create your own KNOWN type, defined with parameters `CaseID`, `CaseName`, etc. Use this type in your Select-method and then `emailList` can then be defined as `IQueryable<MyKnownType>`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface that denotes a type that can be notified by email

```
public interface IEmailNotifiable
{
    EmailContent Content {get;} 
}
```

Then change `IQueryable emailList;` to `IQueryable<IEmailNotifiable>;`

Then create some further classes that implement this interface, which you construct in your select statement.

```
emailList = context.vwMaterialsDueAutoEmail.Select(d => new 
        MaterialsDueEmailNotification(d.CaseID, d.CaseName, d.EmailAddress));
```

So long as `MaterialsDueEmailNotification` implements `IEmailNotifiable`, this can be validly converted because `IQueryable<T>` is covariant.

Then:

```
foreach (var email in emailList) 
{
    SendEmail(email.Content);
}
```

Now I've not only solved the type problem but also devolved the structure of the exact content of the email to the appropriate class, so theoretically, the content and structure of the emails could be varied considerably depending upon the class created.

Comment: Thanks TheInnerLight, Great posts from you and Martin. It makes sense.